# CMD file extension files are opening in notepad instead of being executed

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, steam

I am using steam to execute games and one game's execution start is a CMD file. However, it is opening in notepad rather than executing.

Somewhere along the way I did this. How do I fix it to execute the CMD.

I tried instructions from being having the same issue as BAT files but the CMD change is not in the same place.
[Batch files don't run - they're being opened with notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905708/batch-files-dont-run-theyre-being-opened-with-notepad)

Also, I have the option set to display file extensions. So it is not a case of `FILE.CMD.TXT`

Comment: What instructions did you try before?  The ones here? http://superuser.com/questions/1167421/cmd-file-extension-files-are-opening-in-notepad-instead-of-being-executed?  Something else?

Comment: `set pathext&assoc .cmd&for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %G in ('assoc .cmd') do @ftype %G` Run above from an open `cmd` prompt. Run `reg query hkcr\cmdfile\shell -ve` and `reg query hkcr\cmdfile\shell\open\command -ve` as well. Then, [edit] your question and share the result.

Comment: Get the .CMD file association registry fix [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)

Answer (score -1):

go to the CMD file you want to steam run that for you and right click on it and change the default application ( open with ) to the CMD and check the use this app instead or use this app always . maybe you changed the default app for cmd file into notepad by mistake when u wanted edit cmd files in notepad ! easy . 
go to windows settings and search for default apps ( try this one too there - reset to the microsoft recommended defaults ) click on the choose default apps by file type and u will get a full list of file extension and the default app that are opening them so u can change from notepad into the cmd and here is the address of the cmd if its hard for you to find it :

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe